# sql code to display max views from each category where id is greater than 4

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have table => post

```
 id  || category || views
-------------------------------
 1   |  cat1    |  100
 2   |  cat2    | 2900  <==== most views in cat 2
 3   |  cat3    |  200
 4   |  cat1    | 1900  <==== most views in cat 1
 5   |  cat1    |  800
 6   |  cat2    |  800
 7   |  cat3    | 2700  <==== most views in cat 3
 8   |  cat2    |  900
 9   |  cat3    |  100
 10  |  cat1    |  100
 11  |  cat2    |  1200
 12  |  cat3    |  1500
 13  |  cat3    |  1100
 14  |  cat2    |  1700
 15  |  cat1    |  100
```

now if arrange just for understanding by clicking on the category tab it will arrange the table like this in my database:

```
   id  || category || views
    -------------------------------
     1   |  cat1    |  5100  <==== most views in cat 1
     4   |  cat1    |  1900  
     5   |  cat1    |  800
     10  |  cat1    |  100
     15  |  cat1    |  100

     5   |  cat2    | 2000  <==== most views in cat 2
     6   |  cat2    |  800
     8   |  cat2    |  900
     11  |  cat2    |  1200
     14  |  cat2    |  1700

     3   |  cat3    |  200
     7   |  cat3    | 3000  <==== most views in cat 3
     9   |  cat3    |  100
     12  |  cat3    |  1500
     13  |  cat3    |  1100
```

now i want the sql code first to check the row with max views in cat 1 which is id no. 1 as shown above. Now if that row (i.e. id no.1) having id less than equal to 4 ,then do not show any row of that category here i dont want the sql code to recheck for another row with max views after skip id no.1 , once row with max having id less than equal to 4 sql code should skip that category ,no row of that category should display in results.
now check this for next category and loop .

i want now to give desired output like this :

```
     id  || category || views
    -------------------------------
     5   |  cat2    |  2000  <==== most views in cat 2
     14  |  cat2    |  1700
     11  |  cat2    |  1200
     8   |  cat2    |  900
     6   |  cat2    |  800

     7   |  cat3    | 3000  <==== most views in cat 3
     12  |  cat3    |  1500
     13  |  cat3    |  1100
     3   |  cat3    |  200
     9   |  cat3    |  100
```

**NOTE** : the gap in between cat1 and cat2 is just for distinguishing the category and your understanding ,i dont want that gap in my output.

Now after checking the max views having id greater than 4 the output should order category wise because there are more than 1 rows in each category in desired output i want it to further order by views as shown above .

now i also want to order the desired output table in order of max views like this:

```
     id  || category || views
    -------------------------------
     7   |  cat3    | 3000  <==== most views in cat 3
     12  |  cat3    |  1500
     13  |  cat3    |  1100
     3   |  cat3    |  200
     9   |  cat3    |  100

     5   |  cat2    |  2000  <==== most views in cat 2
     14  |  cat2    |  1700
     11  |  cat2    |  1200
     8   |  cat2    |  900
     6   |  cat2    |  800
```

since  value of id 7 is less than id 5

**THANKS IN ADVANCE.**

my query i edited @radim baca :

```
select p0.*
from post p0 
join post p1 on p0.category= p1.category
join
(
    select p2.category, max(p2.views) as max_views
    from post p2
    group by p2.category
) p2 on p2.category= p1.category and 
        p2.max_views = p1.views and
        p1.id > 4 order by p2.max_views desc, category desc , views desc
```

Comment: i read out three times but don't get what you actually want ..make simple if-else condition ...to solve out problem easily.

Comment: i added query i used

Comment: Is your desired output correct?

Comment: let me edit it for better understanding

Comment: Probably its better if you explain how views are calculated, right next to each in desired output as it doesn't match your original data.

Comment: now check the post

Comment: Take your time, correct your typos, give all details, explain your question. I read your post multiple times, and its just doesn't add up.

Comment: ok i will do it again

Answer (score 1):

If you want rows from `post` table where the row with highest `views` value per such `category` has `id` more than 4 then use the following query:

```
select p0.*
from post p0 
join post p1 on p0.category= p1.category
join
(
    select p2.category, max(p2.views) as max_views
    from post p2
    group by p2.category
) p2 on p2.category= p1.category and 
        p2.max_views = p1.views and
        p1.id > 4
order by p2.max_views desc, p0.vview desc
```

Comment: got some problem pls check.

Comment: its not solved , check the last part of post i editeded.

Comment: @tarun so the problem is in the final ordering, right?

Comment: yes, i have add order clause in your code and output is now working. pls check the  code i edited and tell if it is correct or not , i am posting the code in post above pls check and ont forget to intimate if code is right or wrong

Comment: @tarun I've added the order by. check it.

Answer (score 0):

Chekout this :

```
create table demo(id int , category nvarchar(max) , vview int)

insert into demo(id,category,vview)  values 
(1,'cat1',100),(2,'cat1',500),(3,'cat2',400),(4,'cat2',1100),
(5,'cat3',700),(6,'cat3',1800),(7,'cat1',5800),(8,'cat3',3500)

select id, rank() over(partition by category order by vview desc)  rankk , 
category , vview from demo order by rankk
```

Works at here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e5f89

Answer (score 0):

Find the largest value for each cat.  Build a temp table with just that info.

```
cat2  2000
cat3  3000

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (PRIMARY KEY cat)
    SELECT cat, MAX(views) AS max_views FROM post GROUP BY cat;
```

We will be using the numbers in stead of the names for the eventual sorting.

```
SELECT cat, views
    FROM post
    JOIN t USING(cat)
    ORDER BY t.max_views DESC, post.views DESC;
```

(I don't understand the constraint about `id>4`)